# Jscrollpane scrollbar on a toggled div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

Im working on a website that has an onclick menu that toggles my content divs.
Now im trying to get a custom scrollbar on that div but I cant seem to find a plugin that actually works. Im not sure if its even possible to get this done...

this is my code

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slide-fade-content.js"></script>
<!--Jscrollpane-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<!--Jscrollmousewheel-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<!--Jscrollstyle-->
<link href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>
    $(function(){
    $('#menu a').click(function () {
        $('#menu a').css('background', 'none');
     $(this).css('background', '#00d6f6');
     });
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left">
            <center><img src="images/logo.png"></center>
            <div id="menu">
                <center><a class="more" href="#first-item"><b>Portfolio</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="more" href="#second-item"><b>About Me</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="more" href="#third-item"><b>Services</b></a><br></center>
                <center><a class="more" href="#fourth-item"><b>Contact</b></a></center>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">© DNDesign 2014</div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="ajax" class="scroll-pane"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
</script>
```

this is the CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

p {
    color: #fff;
}

#container {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(images/background.png) repeat-y fixed #000;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#left {
    width:320px;
    height:100%;
    background: #121212;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 10px double black;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#menu {
    width: 300px;
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:18px;
    font-style: oblique;
}

a:hover {
    background: #00d6f6;
}

#footer {
    width: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

#content {
    width: 600px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    float: left;
    background: url(images/background-left1.png) bottom left no-repeat, url(images/background-left2.png) bottom right no-repeat, url(images/background-left4.png) top left no-repeat, url(images/background-left3.png) top right no-repeat, url(images/logobottom.png) bottom center no-repeat;
}

#ajax {
    margin-top: 113px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.scroll-pane {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

this is the code for the ajax div:

```
/* jQuery Color Fade v0.1 * Released under the CC BY 3.0 License (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) * https://github.com/matthewbj/jQuery-Color-Fade */
(function(b){var c={init:function(a){var c=b.extend({fadeColor:"#00d6f6",fadeTime:800,delayTime:600},a),d={position:"relative","z-index":1},e={height:"100%",width:"100%","background-color":c.fadeColor,position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,"z-index":"-1"};return this.each(function(a){b(this).css(d).append('<div id="colorFadeDiv'+a+'" class="colorFadeClass"></div>');b("#colorFadeDiv"+a).css(e).delay(c.delayTime).fadeOut(c.fadeTime)})},refade:function(a){a=b.extend({fadeColor:"#00d6f6",fadeTime:800,delayTime:600},
a);b(this).find(".colorFadeClass").css("background-color",a.fadeColor).show().delay(a.delayTime).fadeOut(a.fadeTime)}};b.fn.colorFade=function(a){if(c[a])return c[a].apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));if("object"===typeof a||!a)return c.init.apply(this,arguments);b.error("Method "+a+" does not exist on jQuery.colorFade")}})(jQuery);

// slide & fade content
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.more').on('click', function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
            $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'0' }).empty();
        }
        $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'450px' },function() {
            $('#ajax').html('<img id="loader" src="loader.gif">');
            $('#loader').css({ border:'none', position:'relative', top:'24px', left:'48px', boxShadow:'none' }); // http://loadinfo.net/
            $('#ajax').load('slide-fade-content.html ' + href, function() {
                $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn('slow').colorFade({ 'fadeColor': '#00d6f6' });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

the page that has the divs which are loaded into the ajax div

```
<div id="load">
<div id="first-item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
</div>
<div id="second-item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
</div>
<div id="third-item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
</div>
<div id="fourth-item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
</div>
```

basically i have one extra page that has the divs with the content for each menu link page. When you click on one of the menu buttons it retrieves one of those divs from the other webpage (which isnt visible on the site itself) and shows it within the div with the ajax ID. So I'm thinking i need to put the scrollbar on that div.

Edit: I've tried to implement Jscrollpane into my code, but its not showing...what am i doing wrong? Also, I havent edited anything yet in the original CSS that comes with Jscrollpane, so that cant be the problem.

Comment: There is no code that changes your content via ajax. Can you make an example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Im not asking to change my content via ajax, Im asking why that Jscrollpane scrollbar isnt showing in my div. The whole stuff with the other code makes perfect snese to me its really an on (menu) click div toggle, thats all

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is ajax update itself - updating content after applying jScrollPane removes custom scrollbar elements (which are located inside of your container), so you should reinitialize jScrollPane to see scrollbars after ajax update. To avoid it you should use method `getContentPane` to get element to update. JavaScirpt update [demo](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_content.html).

Instead of this plugin you can try [jQuery Scrollbar](http://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar/), where you can update content using element id, or class selector `$('.element-class').not('.scroll-wrapper').html(content)` which you can safely use even if jQuery Scrollbar is not initialized

Comment: Ive added all the code for that page, including the piece of Jquery that has to do with the ajax div. I made a small mistake, thought it was in the main page, I'm sorry. The ajax div doesnt upload itself like in the demo you've showed me, so i still cant get it to work.
My bad for not giving all the necessary code.
Hope this shows abit better what exactly happens and how I should fix this

Comment: @Juzbeingme but you do update #ajax content with `$('#ajax').load('slide-fade-content.html '`, so you do remove custom scrollbars. You should reinit jScrollPane after content is loaded. Make example in jsFiddle

Comment: http://perishablepress.com/demos/slide-fade-content/ thats the exact demo of what happens to the ajax div, im just starting to use jquery so id have no idea on how to set it up in JsFiddle since it loads the content from an external page. But on that page is a link to the tut aswell. Id have to change that JScrollPane to not use the append method i think? But to what do i change it...